# Ajax.ActionLink not hitting POST controller method intermittently

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have been experiencing a strange problem.  I basically have an `Ajax.ActionLink` that is used for pagination:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(Model.PaginationText.ToString(), Model.ActionName, Model.RouteValues,
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                    UpdateTargetId = "ajax-append",
                    LoadingElementDuration = 1000,
                    OnBegin = "OnAjaxRequestBeginPaging",
                    OnFailure = "OnAjaxRequestFailure",
                    OnSuccess = "OnAjaxRequestSuccess",
                    OnComplete = "OnAjaxRequestComplete",
                    HttpMethod = "POST"
                }, new Dictionary<string, object>() {{"class", "btn btn-more js-only"}, {"id", "ajaxPaging"}})
```

In my controller method, I have two index methods for GET and POST

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(NewsPage currentPage, int? pageNo)
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(NewsPage currentPage, int pageNo, bool? isAjax)
```

This all seems correct, however when clicked, the clink drops into the GET method intermittently.

I have been debugging for hours but I cannot seem to consistently get the code to POST.

Has anyone any ideas on this?

Thanks

Comment: any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: None at all, it really is bizarre...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Ajax.Beginform instead of an ActionLink which seemed to work much better.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not able to parse your AjaxOptions and hence ignoring your HttpMethod setting. Try debugging with minimal AjaxOptions.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but still no joy here!